# Mup error with docker and mongodb while deploying to Digital Ocean

Tags: mongodb, docker, meteor, deployment, mup

I am trying to deploy a Meteor app using mup, and it is giving me all the time this error:

```
[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] x Start Mongo: FAILED

          ------------------------------------STDERR------------------------------------
          Error response from daemon: Container a1617b2aaaa3fd4aeb8e1241ec90ae32b4a88b0df9c95e5d73de608b68788ef0 is not running
    docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint mongodb (2f5db292f7022a39dfe3ff5fdf5ed7de38ddc7bb6f787625cd0fb45a5fa10cd6): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:27017: bind: address already in use.

          ------------------------------------STDOUT------------------------------------
          3.2.15: Pulling from library/mongo
    Digest: sha256:ef3277c7221e8512a1657ad90dfa2ad13ae2e35aacce6cd7defabbbdcf67ca76
    Status: Image is up to date for mongo:3.2.15
    mongodb
    mongodb
    Running mongo:3.2.15
    97a28fe9d2dca6130ffe6622e662a230ecea34214920673c574a4d3e57fafb3c

          ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I have checked and I can connect through ssh to the server. I am using one of the One-click droplets from Digital Ocean because it came with Mongodb installed already. The version of Mongodb on the server is 3.4 and in my app I am using 3.2.15, I do not know if I should downgrade or upgrade either one or the other, or if even if the problem is there.

My mup.js file looks like this:

```
module.exports = {  servers: {
one: {
  host: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
  username: 'root',
  pem: '~/.ssh/id_rsa'
  // or neither for authenticate from ssh-agent
}
},
meteor: {
name: 'myApp',
path: '../myApp/',

servers: {
  one: {},
},

buildOptions: {
  serverOnly: true,
},

env: {
  // If you are using ssl, it needs to start with https://
  ROOT_URL: 'http://app.com',
  "PORT": 80,
  MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://localhost/local',
  //MONGO_OPLOG_URL: 'mongodb://mongodb/local',
},
deployCheckWaitTime: 60,

docker: {
  // change to 'abernix/meteord:base' if your app is using Meteor 1.4 - 1.5
  image: 'abernix/meteord:base',
},

// Show progress bar while uploading bundle to server
// You might need to disable it on CI servers
enableUploadProgressBar: true
},

mongo: {
version: '3.2.15',
servers: {
  one: {}
}
},
};
```

I am going crazy with this, can someone help me please?

Comment: Try creating a one click droplet with ubuntu instead of mongo as mup sets up mongo for you already.

Comment: It worked! I finally got it using a fresh new Ubuntu 14 droplet. I did not know that mup set up Mongodb for you already, and the one I was installing in the server was messing it up with the one mup was creating.
Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Great! I'll create this as the answer then, if you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a one click droplet on Digital Ocean with Ubuntu instead of mongo as mup sets up mongo for you already. I believe Meteor UP assumes it's doing the deploy from fresh settings.

Comment: Diegaker it's good form to mark the answer from @kyle-bachan as correct